# how to stop autoplay in swiper immediately on hover

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, swiper.js, autoplay

I have a swiper which is autoplay and when i hover over it it should stop immediately, now it finishes the transition and only after that it stops

Here is the question how can I stop it immediately at the place where the cursor was hovered, without waiting for the end of the transition

Can I somehow interrupt the transition maibe

Here is Swiper config on Vue

```
this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-brand-container', {
      loop: true,
      spaceBetween: 120,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      centeredSlides: true,
      nested: true,
      speed: 5000,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 0,
      },
    });
```

and functions for stop and start autoplay

```
stopAutoplay() {
      if (this.swiper) {
        this.swiper.autoplay.stop();
      }
    },
startAutoplay() {
      if (this.swiper) {
        this.swiper.autoplay?.start();
      }
    },
```

1. I tried to recreate the swiper without autoplay
2. tried to influence the swiper container through styles
3. Change parameters dynamically

couldn't find any information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't find any answer, and no one gave any advice, I had to somehow get out of my way and I didn't think of anything better than to do this scrolling myself

```
stopAutoplay() {
      if (this.swiper) {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
      }
    },
    startAutoplay() {
      const slideCount = this.swiper.slidesGrid.length
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.translate = this.translate + 30
        if (this.translate > this.swiper.slidesGrid[slideCount - 3]) {
          this.translate = this.swiper.slidesGrid[0]
        }
        this.$refs.wrapper.style = `transform: translate3d(-${this.translate}px, 0px, 0px)`

      }, 500)
    },
```

I just add an interval, and every half a second I move the block by a couple of pixels, and if I need to stop scrolling, I remove the interval

it's not perfect, so if you have ideas on how to improve, please write

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<template>
  <div
    class="swiper-brand-container"
    @mouseenter="stopAutoplay"
    @mouseleave="startAutoplay"
  >
    <!-- Your Swiper content goes here -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Or this

```
<template>
  <div
    class="swiper-brand-container"
    @mouseenter="freezeSlider"
    @mouseleave="unfreezeSlider"
  >
    <!-- Your Swiper content goes here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      swiper: null,
      isFrozen: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initSwiper();
  },
  methods: {
    initSwiper() {
      this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-brand-container', {
        loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 120,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        centeredSlides: true,
        nested: true,
        speed: 5000,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 0,
        },
      });
    },
    freezeSlider() {
      if (this.swiper && !this.isFrozen) {
        this.swiper.autoplay.stop();
        this.swiper.params.autoplay.delay = 0;
        this.swiper.params.speed = 0;
        this.isFrozen = true;
      }
    },
    unfreezeSlider() {
      if (this.swiper && this.isFrozen) {
        this.swiper.params.autoplay.delay = 5000; // Back to default
        this.swiper.params.speed = 5000; // Back to default
        this.swiper.autoplay.start();
        this.isFrozen = false;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: it still waits for the end of the transition and only then stops, but i need to stop swiper immediately on hover, without waiting for the end of the transition, like pause transition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).